# Apache web server - purge log files

Tags: apache, logging

We have Apache server running in a server and using rotate logs, we roll logs .

I can set up autopsy’s job to remove them . But does Apache have any log4j setup to roll up logs and keep only n number of rolled up logs.
Is there any way to purge them automatically which is 30 day old.

So i use following format and works fine to roll them and it works fine here

```
  CustomLog "|/local/web/apache24/bin/rotatelogs /local/web/apache24/logs/${instancename}.accesstest_log_v.%Y-%m%d%H%M 86400" common
```

what would be the option to limit to number of files, I tried below  and its not working

```
CustomLog "|/local/web/apache24/bin/rotatelogs -n 5 /local/web/apache24/logs/${instancename}.accesstest_log_v.%Y-%m%d%H%M 86400" common
```

Comment: Apache doesn't use java, hence no log4j. It has rotatelogs though : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html ... that said, don't think rotatelogs does erase or manage the log otherwise than rotating them. I personally use scripting to manage my logs.

Comment: If I use rotatelogs and use rotation time 1 day and let’s say I want to keep 30 days worth log , what do be the syntax ..

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: Like I said, I use scripting to manage my logs (compress, erase). But then again, you might want to try setting the rotationtime to 86400 (24hrs) and use the "number-of-file" parameters at 30. From what I understand, after logfile.29 it will overwrite the first file (logfile). But that's not a good solution from my standpoint, hence my use of custom script to take care of that.

Comment: ok thats same as what log4j does in java. i havent seen any marginal performance impact. are you saying it is a marginal performance differencee.

Comment: Actually not a difference in performance, but for operational support. My logs, access, error and SSL, are all with date suffixes and in sub-directories named by dates. Easier for me to find the proper one in case of troubleshooting. Also, easier for me to have the same configuration in httpd.conf over all environments and customize my scripts (dev will be kept 90 days but production only 30 days by example).

Comment: what will be the option for number of files?

Comment: What do you mean ? for rotatelogs...all in the link I've provided earlier.

Comment: edited my qn, with -n 5 option, it just doesnt create log , i mean process doesnt even start for log though all other process are started

Comment: try with : 'CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs........ ' typically path are relative to the server root.